# View not being updated when ViewModel gets new data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mvvm, swiftui

I have an app that will make an API call once a day to retrieve new data.

When the app launches it will check if new data is available, save new data to core data, call core data to show data in a view.

**Issue**
After saving new data to core data my view will not display the newly save data, but instead display the default dummy data from my model. The new data will be displayed after relaunching the app.

**Question**
How can I display the newly save data in the view without having to relaunch the app? I'm using MVVM pattern. Below is my code with links to my code.

[UVIndexNowModel](https://github.com/Mattenhour/UV-Index/blob/master/UV%20Index/Model/UVIndexNowModel.swift)

```
class UVIndexNowModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var uvIndex: Int
    @Published var dateTime: Date
    
    init(uvIndex: Int = 0, dateTime: Date = Date())
    {
        self.uvIndex = uvIndex
        self.dateTime = dateTime
    }
}
```

[UVIndexNowViewModel](https://github.com/Mattenhour/UV-Index/blob/master/UV%20Index/ViewModel/UVIndexNowViewModel.swift)

```
class UVIndexNowViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject
{
    private var isFirstAppearance = true
    private let moc = PersistentStore.shared.context
    private let nowController: NSFetchedResultsController<UVHour>
    
    @Published var data: UVIndexNowModel = UVIndexNowModel()
    @Published var coreDateError: Bool = false
    
    override init()
    {
        nowController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: UVHour.uvIndexNowRequest,
                                                   managedObjectContext: moc,
                                                   sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        super.init()
        
        nowController.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try nowController.performFetch()
            let results = nowController.fetchedObjects ?? []
            
            setUVIndex(from: results)
            
        } catch {
            print("failed to fetch items!")
        }
    }
    
    func setUVIndex(from hours: [UVHour])
    {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = .current
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM/d/yyyy hh a"

        let todaystr = formatter.string(from: date)
        
        print("UVIndexNowVM.setUVIndex() size of UVHour array: \(hours.count)")
        
        for i in hours
        {
            let tempDateStr = formatter.string(from: i.wrappedDateTime)

            if todaystr == tempDateStr
            {
                print("UV Now VM Date matches! \(tempDateStr)")
                
                self.data.uvIndex = i.wrappedUVIndex
                self.data.dateTime = i.wrappedDateTime
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
}

extension UVIndexNowViewModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
{
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
    {
        print("UVIndexNowViewModel controllerDidChangeContent was called. New Stuff in DB")
        guard let results = controller.fetchedObjects as? [UVHour] else { return }
        
        setUVIndex(from: results)
    }
}
```

[UVIndexNowView](https://github.com/Mattenhour/UV-Index/blob/master/UV%20Index/Views/UVIndexNowView.swift)

```
struct UVIndexNowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = UVIndexNowViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(vm.data.dateTime)")
            Text("UV Index: \(vm.data.uvIndex)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `UVIndexNowModel` is-a `ObservableObject` you need to observe it in separated view, like

```
struct UVIndexNowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = UVIndexNowViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
       UVIndexNowDataView(data: vm.data)    // << here !!
    }
}
```

and

```
struct UVIndexNowDataView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: UVIndexNowModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(data.dateTime)")
            Text("UV Index: \(data.uvIndex)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use [Binding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) since the source of truth would be stored in a different view?

Comment: No, you use reference type model, it is already, by nature, referenced to source of truth.